# I can get this to run without def total_numbers(number_set): but not with it. Why?

Tags: python, loops

I would like to create a function using a for loop that totals up a list of numbers. I know there are some inbuilt functions in python for this but would like to use something like below.

I can get this to run without def total_numbers(number_set): but not with it.

Why not?

```
number_set = [1, 12, 23, 16]

def total_numbers(number_set):
    total = 0
    for number in number_set:
        total += number
    print(total)
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you know what `def` does? It's not just a fun decoration; it has a point and changes the meaning of your code.

Comment: You are sort of sitting around staring at a button, not pressing it, but then wondering why the button does nothing. Also -- it would be much more idiomatic to `return` the sum rather than `print` it. Let the code that calls the function decide if it wants to print the result (or do something else with it). Functions which print their results are in general much less useful.

Answer (score 2):

With `def` you **define** a method, you create and only create it, you don't use it (**call** it)

To call it, take its name put parenthesis and fill the parameters

```
def total_numbers(number_set):
    total = 0
    for number in number_set:
        total += number
    print(total)

values = [1, 12, 23, 16]
total_numbers(values)
```